# Which setup is best for domains and languages in magento?

Tags: magento-1.8, multistore, multicurrency

How do I get this setup best as possible?

We have multi domains like .com .co.uk, .de, .es, .fr and so on. Why we do this is so people can shop on their respective country specific domain, language, currency.

All domains should have the same products, but the prices are not exactly the same.

Lets say base price is 34.99, then in euro it would be 26.15 but we want 25.99 and so on, so we are getting an easy pricing structure for each domain.

What is the best set up?

Different websites to each domain or is it possible to the above with just storeviews?

Comment: Thx for your answer :) But all the language things are handled by people that can each language. The price update thing is not our biggest concerns. So it's more how the best setup will be.

Comment: Well if we go op for that amount of sku's it would probally be a solution, but we will only hit around 500 :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want different prices on different domains (and you don't want to code or look for extensions) then separate websites is the way to go.
Simple as that.
Magento supports this out of the box for multiple websites configuration.
For one website / multiples store views this is not possible out of the box. There are a few extensions out there that do this, but I would not rely on them to do the job if you have an alternative.

Comment: Thx for your answer :)